# Avoid duplicate data PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql

How do i insert these `artist` into database only if `does not` exist in database. I have written following code. But it is wrong. Will you please help me ? thanks

Artist List

```
Lata Mangeshkar  
Lata Mangeshkar
Lata Mangeshkar
Asha Bhosle
Lata Mangeshkar
Mahendra Kapoor  
Lata Mangeshkar
Kishore Kumar
Lata Mangeshkar
```

My code

```
for l in artist:
        l = l.strip()
        cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM song_artist WHERE name = %s ;" ,(l,) ) # Id exist?
        artist_rows = cursor.fetchone()
        if not artist_rows:
            artist_slug = self.makeSlug(artist[0])
            cursor.execute( 'INSERT INTO song_artist (name,slug) VALUES (%s,%s) RETURNING id;',(artist[0],artist_slug))
            print k
```

Output :

```
INSERT INTO song_artist (name,slug) VALUES (Lata Mangeshkar,lata-mangeshkar) RET
URNING id;
INSERT INTO song_artist (name,slug) VALUES (Lata Mangeshkar,lata-mangeshkar) RET
URNING id;
INSERT INTO song_artist (name,slug) VALUES (Lata Mangeshkar,lata-mangeshkar) RET
URNING id;
INSERT INTO song_artist (name,slug) VALUES (Lata Mangeshkar,lata-mangeshkar) RET
URNING id;
INSERT INTO song_artist (name,slug) VALUES (Asha Bhosle,asha-bhosle) RETURNING i
d;
INSERT INTO song_artist (name,slug) VALUES (Lata Mangeshkar,lata-mangeshkar) RET
URNING id;
INSERT INTO song_artist (name,slug) VALUES (Mahendra Kapoor,mahendra-kapoor) RET
URNING id;
INSERT INTO song_artist (name,slug) VALUES (Mahendra Kapoor,mahendra-kapoor) RET
URNING id;
INSERT INTO song_artist (name,slug) VALUES (Lata Mangeshkar,lata-mangeshkar) RET
URNING id;
```

OUTPUT SHOULD BE:

```
INSERT INTO song_artist (name,slug) VALUES (Asha Bhosle,asha-bhosle) RETURNING i
d;
INSERT INTO song_artist (name,slug) VALUES (Lata Mangeshkar,lata-mangeshkar) RET
URNING id;
INSERT INTO song_artist (name,slug) VALUES (Mahendra Kapoor,mahendra-kapoor) RET
URNING id;
```

UPDATE:

I have already Added constraint on the column name to enforce the column is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `if not artist_rows:` That's all

```
    artist_slug = self.makeSlug(l)

cursor.execute("SELECT count(id) FROM song_artist WHERE name = %s and slug = %s ;" ,(l,artist_slug) ) # Id exist?
artist_rows = cursor.fetchone()
#artist_rows = artist_rows[0]
db.commit()
if not artist_rows:
cursor.execute( 'INSERT INTO song_artist (name,slug) VALUES (%s,%s) RETURNING id;',(l,artist_slug))
#k=( 'INSERT INTO song_artist (name,slug) SELECT %s,%s WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 42 FROM song_artist WHERE name = %s) RETURNING id;'%(l,artist_slug,l))
artist_id = cursor.fetchone()[0] # get mysql_insert_id using RETURNING
db.commit()
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Enforce that on the database side. Add constraint on the column name to enforce the column is unique. This should be enough:

   ALTER TABLE song_artist ADD UNIQUE (name);

   This way you can be sure that whatever you do, you won't have any duplicated values.
2. You could insert the data using queries like this:

   INSERT INTO song_artist (name, slug)
   SELECT 'Mahendra Kapoor','mahendra-kapoor'
   WHERE NOT EXISTS
     (
       SELECT 42
       FROM song_artist
       WHERE name = 'Mahendra Kapoor'
     );

Comment: It is complicated. what is 42?

Comment: I tried your code. But not working. Getting error message. `psycopg2.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "song_ar
tist_slug_key"
DETAIL:  Key (slug)=(lata-mangeshkar) already exists.`

Comment: That's because you already have duplicated data. Delete the duplicates and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the unique constraint as Szymon Guz suggested,

```
ALTER TABLE song_artist ADD UNIQUE (name);
```

Then use a try / except to handle the duplicate error:

```
try:
  cursor.execute( 'INSERT INTO song_artist (name,slug) VALUES (%s,%s) RETURNING id;',(artist[0],artist_slug))

except psycopg2.IntegrityError:
  debug.print 'Duplicate values found.  Insert was not successful'
```